# What is the equivalent of LINQ-to-SQL's ExecuteCommand in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I am porting an application running on LINQ-to-SQL to **Entity Framework**, and am having trouble finding an equivalent to **ExecuteCommand**:

```
db.ExecuteCommand("INSERT Infos (Title) VALUES ('this is an added title')");
```

I found [this site](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/12/02/migrating-from-linq-to-sql-to-the-entity-framework-stored-procedures-for-data-retrieval.aspx) which tells me that *it is possible to implement ExecuteCommand as an **extension method** on your ObjectContext, leaving the existing code unchanged by adding this code to a static method in your project:*

```
public static int ExecuteCommand(this ObjectContext objectContext,
                                string command) {
    DbConnection connection = ((EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection).StoreConnection;
    bool opening = (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed);
    if (opening)
        connection.Open();

    DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = command;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    try {
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally {
        if (opening && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }
}
```

But I've tried putting it (1) in the class where I use it, (2) in the Entity generated class file, (3) in a static class in the project, but always get various errors. **Where do I need to put this method exactly?**

The above site **also** said:

> ExecuteCommand is being considered as
>   an enhancement for a future release of
>   the Entity Framework

**Does ExecuteCommand() exist in the newest version of Entity Framework?** I am using the Entity Framework that was installed with Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly when trying to use the extension method?

Comment: ok, it compiles when I specify the class that I put it in as *static*, so it seems to work, but I can't get the application to run to test it because of another issue described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708964/why-do-i-get-this-error-when-i-try-to-open-an-mdf-database-via-path-filename-in-e

Comment: This : `CommandType.StoredProcedure` may also have an impact, as I guess you want to execute a request, not a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

.NET Framework 4's [ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext%28VS.100%29.aspx) class has the [ExecuteStoreCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand%28VS.100%29.aspx) and  [ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487195%28VS.100%29.aspx) methods that seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/11/07/tip-41-how-to-execute-t-sql-directly-against-the-database.aspx for EF 1.