# Why do I get this error when I try to open an MDF database via path/filename in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm migrating an application from LINQ-to-SQL to **Entity** **Framework** and have changed the line:

```
using (var db = new MainDataContext(SystemHelpers.GetDatabaseConnectionString()))
```

to

```
using (var db = new MainDataEntities(SystemHelpers.GetDatabaseConnectionString()))
```

where `SystemHelpers.GetDatabaseConnectionString())` is a **file path to an .mdf file**.

It works in LINQ-to-SQL but in Entity Framework the above line gives me this **error**:

> The format of the initialization
>   string conflicts with the
>   specification which begins with '0';

which is the best translation I can do from the German:

> "Das Format der
>   Initialisierungszeichenfolge stimmt
>   nicht mit der Spezifikation überein,
>   die bei Index '0' beginnt."

Comment: Could you pls. post the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework connections string are more complicated than standard connection strings.

They are made up of three parts:

1. the Provider Connection String =>
   this is what you're providing
2. the Metadata => which is where
   the EF should get the CSDL, MSL and
   SSDL from (i.e. Conceptual Model,
   Mapping and Storage Model)
3. the Provider name => i.e. for SQL
   server this is generally
   System.Data.SqlClient

Here is what it one might look like:

metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

Hope this helps

Alex

Answer (score 1):

EF connection strings can't be the DB connection string alone. They *contain* the DB connection string, but they have much more information, too. It sounds like you're trying to use the DB connection string alone. That won't work. See this example for [how to build an EF connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx).